# Class.getAnnotations() does not return full list of Class level Annotations when @PreAuthorize or @PostAuthorize is used inside it on method level

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

Lets say I have a below class with Annotations -

```
@Component
@Path("/somepath/")
@Api(value = "/somepath", description = "Operations")
public class SomeResourceClass {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new Resource", 
        response = SomeResource.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Some Message") })
    public SomeResource createResource(@ApiParam(value="someResource", required = true)SomeResource resource) {
    }
}
```

I am trying to access the list of Annotations used on above Class level using below code

```
List<ClassResourceInfo> classResourceInfos = serverFactoryBean.getServiceFactory().getClassResourceInfo();
for (ClassResourceInfo classResourceInfo : classResourceInfos) {
    for (Annotation annotation : classResourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotations()) {
 // work with each annotation
}
}
```

I get the below list from classResourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotations() -

```
[@org.springframework.stereotype.Component(value=), 
 @javax.ws.rs.Path(value=/somepath/), 
 @io.swagger.annotations.Api(basePath=, hidden=false, authorizations=[@io.swagger.annotations.Authorization(scopes=[@io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope=, description=)], value=)], produces=, description=Operations, position=0, protocols=, value=/somepath, tags=[], consumes=)]
```

So here I get the complete list of Annotations defined on the Class level.

But now if I used the @PreAuthorize on method I get the incomplete list.

```
@Component
@Path("/somepath/")
@Api(value = "/somepath", description = "Operations")
public class SomeResourceClass {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Create new Resource", 
        response = SomeResource.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Some Message") })
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public SomeResource createResource(@ApiParam(value="someResource", required = true)SomeResource resource) {
    }
}
```

List of Annotations defined on the Class level I get in this scenario is -

```
[@io.swagger.annotations.Api(basePath=, hidden=false, authorizations=[@io.swagger.annotations.Authorization(scopes=[@io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope=, description=)], value=)], produces=, description=Operations, position=0, protocols=, value=/somepath, tags=[], consumes=)]
```

I have defined the SomeResourceClass in web-context xml file

```
<jaxrs:server id="service-rest" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="someResourceClass"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Can you help me in pointing out why I am getting the incomplete list of Class level annotations when I use @PreAuthorize annotation on one of its method?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it happens because Spring creates proxy for your controller since you used @PreAuthorize annotation. Please refer to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring) article.

Still you can access target class annotation:

```
public class MetricSuppliersLoader implements ApplicationContextAware {

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    Map<String, Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(SomeAnnotationClass.class);
    beans.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println("Bean name: "+e.getKey()));

}
}
```